# Unable to ad Google AdView

Tags: android

USing Android Studio 2
 I get this error while compiling the code

Gradle: Execution failed for task ':dummy002:compileDebug'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   C:\Android_XML\dummy002Project\dummy002\src\main\java\com\example\dummy002\MainActivity.java\
>   Gradle: package com.google.ads does not exist

I have add the file
GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar in the lib directory and also as library file.

When coding the code does not show any error highlight.

If I use the AdView in Actitvity the preview in studio show banner ads by  google.

Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the line in **dependances** to `build.gradle` file solved the problem

```
"compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "your key");        

AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.setTesting(false);
adView.loadAd(request);

XML File
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId=" a1510b619xxxxx"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Comment: The below solution worked for one simple project but the other now compiles without error but when run on emulator stops at new AdView command.

Comment: In parent layout in you give any padddin ? if padding there then it can be that problem.remove it ...